# MongoDB retrieving selected objects from nested documents

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to query for specific objects within a nested document? Heres an example,

```
Collection : Threads
{
    Documents : Messages
    {
        threadId = 1
        messages = [
            {
                user = amy
                date = 01/01/2012
                content = hey
            },
            {
                user = bell
                date = 01/01/2012
                content = hey
            },
            {
                user = bell
                date = 01/02/2012
                content = whats up
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        threadId = 2
        messages = [
            {
                user = courtney
                date = 01/03/2012
                content = first!
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like my query to say `{ threadId : 1, 'messages.date' : { $gt : 01/01/2012 } }, { fields : { messages : 1 } }`. But it will return all of that documents messages when really all i want as a result is this,

```
messages = [
    {
        user = bell
        date = 01/02/2012
        content = whats up
    }
]
```

Comment: Using MongoDB Aggregations pipelines could provide you a solution !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You cannot return just the selected subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array). You'll get all of them. So you'll have to filter on the client side.